# Python-dbus extra param to add_signal_receiver

Tags: python, signals, dbus

I'd like to pass extra param to add_signal_receiver or get somehow path the signal was received from.
Now it's defined like that:

```
bus.add_signal_receiver(handle_signal, 'RemoteDeviceFound', 'org.bluez.Adapter', 'org.bluez', '/org/bluez/hci'+x)

def handle_signal(address, cls, rssi):
    xxxx
```

I wan't to have many signal receivers at the same time and be able to read 'x' inside handle_signal function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Python [DBUS documenation has your answer](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/doc/tutorial.html#getting-more-information-from-a-signal). It provides the following example to pass the sender to the handler function:

```
def handler(sender=None):
    print "got signal from %r" % sender

iface.connect_to_signal("Hello", handler, sender_keyword='sender')
```

So, instead of using `bus.add_signal_receiver`, create an interface for the signal providing object first and then connect to the signal as in the example.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Oben Sonne's answer, `add_signal_receiver` takes the same arguments:

```
bus = dbus.SystemBus()
bus.add_signal_receiver(handler,
                        sender_keyword='sender',
                        destination_keyword='destination',
                        member_keyword='member',
                        path_keyword='path',
                        interface_keyword='interface')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the path the signal was received from, do this:

```
def handler(path=None):
    print("got signal with path %r" % path)

bus.add_signal_receiver(handler, path_keyword="path")
```

Similarly, you can pass 'sender', 'destination', 'member', and 'interface' as mentioned by others. You cannot forward arbitrary callback information, however.